# How to set xmlns when serializing object in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xml, xml-serialization

I am serializing an object in my ASP.net MVC program to an xml string like this;

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(mytype));
s.Serialize(sw, myData);
```

Now this give me this as the first 2 lines;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<GetCustomerName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

my question is, 
How can I change the xmlns and the encoding type, when serializing?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What I found that works was to add this line to my class,

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://myurl.com/api/v1.0", IsNullable = true)]
```

and add this to my code to add namespace when I call serialize

```
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns1 = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns1.Add("", "http://myurl.com/api/v1.0");
    xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, FormData, ns1);
```

as long as both namespaces match it works well.

Answer (score 11):

The `XmlSerializer` type has a second parameter in its constructor which is the default xml namespace - the "xmlns:" namespace:

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(mytype), "http://yourdefault.com/");
```

To set the encoding, I'd suggest you use a `XmlTextWriter` instead of a straight `StringWriter` and create it something like this:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

XmlTextWriter xtw = XmlWriter.Create(filename, settings);

s.Serialize(xtw, myData);
```

In the `XmlWriterSettings`, you can define a plethora of options - including the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [attributes that control XML serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e(VS.71).aspx) in .NET.

Specifically, the [XmlTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.aspx) may be useful for you. If you're looking to change the default namespace for you XML file, there is a [second parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw0f5wee(v=VS.90).aspx) to the `XmlSerializer` constructor where you can define that.